# Create Manual Pagination for WordPress Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I need to create manual pagination for WordPress custom post type; situation is explained below.

custom post type is 'survey'

I want each survey question to be displayed on single page and then upon clicking next button, the page should be reloaded and the next question should be displayed, So survey's structure should be like

> Starting Page: http://www.example.com/survey-title/
>
> Question 1:    http://www.example.com/survey-title/q/1/
> Question 2:    http://www.example.com/survey-title/q/2/
> Question 3:    http://www.example.com/survey-title/q/3
>
> End Page:      http://www.example.com/survey-title/result/

On the bases of question number(q) passed, I can retrieve the required question.

What are the possible options (without possibly modifying the core wp structure) to achieve this?

**P.S.** it's intended to be similar functionality that we get by using `<!--more-->` tag to split the post/page contents into multiple paginated pages.

Any help regarding is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to create a page to loop your posts with the custom type "survey", give it a number of posts per page and add a small trick to make the pagination work.

Sounds simple? Here's translated in code:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'survey',  //your post type
    'posts_per_page' => 1  // number of posts you want to see per page, in your case, 1
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content()
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next Page' ); ?></div>
```

Are you posting data on every page or saving to POST only at the end? if it's the last case, this is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not what I am looking for, it's simply to display the custom post, I have no issue in displaying the custom post rather I want to paginate it so that can display one question per page, and Yes I am posting the data for each question submit.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand this sentence "it's simply to display the custom post, I have no issue in displaying the custom post" you want or you don't help displaying the custom post? Perhaps my reply is not what you're looking for, but it's the reply to your question, which is a pagination for a custom post type. If you want to display your single post, edit your single file or use a template single-{post_type}.php. In the end, display a link to the next post. If this is what you want, I can edit my reply and show you how to do it.

Comment: May be I am not that clear, let me simplify, I have a post type 'survey' that has multiple questions and answers in it, I want each question (with answer options e.g. MCQs) to be displayed on the separate page and when user submit answer to one question, they should navigate to next page and attempt 2nd question... so basically, survey post is a SINGLE POST and its questions needed to be parted in multiple pages, Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: In order to do that I need to know if all the posts of the type survey compose one survey or if you have more than one survey. If you only have one, you can do the code I showed you, that will loop all the posts and then the next will load the next post in line. You can also produce a single-survey.php that will show the posts of that type and put a simple link to the next page of the survey at the end.

Comment: Thx for reply, There are more than one surveys and each survey has multiple questions, after each question attempt, page should be reloaded to display the next question. P.S.it can be done by JS is not requirement!